# Converting a model to its base model

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models

Consider this file :

```
from django.db import models

class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Restaurant(Place):
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Now, let's say that I have a `Restaurant`, named `restaurant`. But this place is no longer a restaurant, so I want to transform it to a Place. For that, I do :

```
p = Place.objects.get(pk=place_id)
p.restaurant.delete()
p.save()
```

It works well, `p` is no longer a restaurant, but something strange happens : The primary key (ID) of `p` in the Place table change, like if the Place was deleted and then recreated.

Why is this happening ?
And how can I transform my restaurant to a place without changing the place ID ?

Comment: Where does `place_id` come from ?

Comment: @lbris It goes from a form, consider that I have the place and that I know it is a restaurant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You inherited `restaurant` from `place` and `Django` do some stuff about this kind of relation between two table in DB.Django calls that `Multi-table inheritance`.
Some of the features of this type of design include the following:

> 1. `PK` of two objects are same.
> 2. Two object in Django point of view seems as a one object so every change in `PK` of one object cause automatic change in other object.
> 3. There is `an automatically-created OneToOneField` relation between two model.
> 4. There is atomic transaction for query in these objects.

So this is normal behavior of Django ORM and Django manage change in those two object's `PK`. You can read more about this concept with  `concrete model` and `multi-table inheritance` in this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance).